# After upgrading Ubuntu 20 LTS to 22 LTS, kubernetes (apiserver) won't start

Tags: upgrade, 22.04, kubernetes

I just upgraded my single-node Kubernetes cluster VM from Ubuntu 20 LTS to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. Most of the applications start properly, but I can't get my Kubernetes cluster to start.

For some reason, the apiserver starts, but after a few seconds stops / crashes. After a few minutes or so, it briefly starts again, only to crash. I can't figure out what happens...

Anyone have any debugging tips? I don't have a unit for the apiserver in journalctl.

Kubernetes cluster created with kubeadm. Kubelet, kubeadm, kubectl version 1.28.2.

Obviously, `kubectl get nodes` doesn't return anything, besides `connection refused` (since the apiserver is not running).

Journalctl -u kubelet (can't post everything, because of max post size):

```
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 systemd[1]: Started kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent.
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: Flag --container-runtime-endpoint has been deprecated, This parameter should be set via the config file specified by the Kubelet's --config flag. See https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubelet-config-file/ for more information.
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: Flag --pod-infra-container-image has been deprecated, will be removed in a future release. Image garbage collector will get sandbox image information from CRI.
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.221666   11023 server.go:203] "--pod-infra-container-image will not be pruned by the image garbage collector in kubelet and should also be set in the remote runtime"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.226362   11023 server.go:467] "Kubelet version" kubeletVersion="v1.28.2"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.226385   11023 server.go:469] "Golang settings" GOGC="" GOMAXPROCS="" GOTRACEBACK=""
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.226717   11023 server.go:895] "Client rotation is on, will bootstrap in background"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.228378   11023 certificate_store.go:130] Loading cert/key pair from "/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem".
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.229694   11023 dynamic_cafile_content.go:157] "Starting controller" name="client-ca-bundle::/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.239370   11023 server.go:725] "--cgroups-per-qos enabled, but --cgroup-root was not specified.  defaulting to /"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.239750   11023 container_manager_linux.go:265] "Container manager verified user specified cgroup-root exists" cgroupRoot=[]
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.239961   11023 container_manager_linux.go:270] "Creating Container Manager object based on Node Config" nodeConfig={"RuntimeCgroupsName":"","SystemCgroupsName":"","KubeletCgroupsName":"","KubeletOOMScoreAdj":-999,"ContainerRuntime":"","CgroupsPerQOS":true,"CgroupRoot":"/","CgroupDriver":"systemd","KubeletRootDir":"/var/lib/kubelet","ProtectKernelDefaults":false,"KubeReservedCgroupName":"","SystemReservedCgroupName":"","ReservedSystemCPUs":{},"EnforceNodeAllocatable":{"pods":{}},"KubeReserved":null,"SystemReserved":null,"HardEvictionThresholds":[{"Signal":"memory.available","Operator":"LessThan","Value":{"Quantity":"100Mi","Percentage":0},"GracePeriod":0,"MinReclaim":null},{"Signal":"nodefs.available","Operator":"LessThan","Value":{"Quantity":null,"Percentage":0.1},"GracePeriod":0,"MinReclaim":null},{"Signal":"nodefs.inodesFree","Operator":"LessThan","Value":{"Quantity":null,"Percentage":0.05},"GracePeriod":0,"MinReclaim":null},{"Signal":"imagefs.available","Operator":"LessThan","Value":{"Quantity":null,"Percentage":0.15},"GracePeriod":0,"MinReclaim":null}],"QOSReserved":{},"CPUManagerPolicy":"none","CPUManagerPolicyOptions":null,"TopologyManagerScope":"container","CPUManagerReconcilePeriod":10000000000,"ExperimentalMemoryManagerPolicy":"None","ExperimentalMemoryManagerReservedMemory":null,"PodPidsLimit":-1,"EnforceCPULimits":true,"CPUCFSQuotaPeriod":100000000,"TopologyManagerPolicy":"none","TopologyManagerPolicyOptions":null}
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240005   11023 topology_manager.go:138] "Creating topology manager with none policy"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240016   11023 container_manager_linux.go:301] "Creating device plugin manager"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240075   11023 state_mem.go:36] "Initialized new in-memory state store"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240201   11023 kubelet.go:393] "Attempting to sync node with API server"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240233   11023 kubelet.go:298] "Adding static pod path" path="/etc/kubernetes/manifests"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240287   11023 kubelet.go:309] "Adding apiserver pod source"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.240339   11023 apiserver.go:42] "Waiting for node sync before watching apiserver pods"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: W0102 14:03:49.241034   11023 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlabs-devops01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.241150   11023 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Node: failed to list *v1.Node: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/api/v1/nodes?fieldSelector=metadata.name%3Dlabs-devops01&limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: W0102 14:03:49.241149   11023 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.241243   11023 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.Service: failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.241876   11023 kuberuntime_manager.go:257] "Container runtime initialized" containerRuntime="containerd" version="1.7.2" apiVersion="v1"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.242663   11023 server.go:1232] "Started kubelet"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.243305   11023 ratelimit.go:65] "Setting rate limiting for podresources endpoint" qps=100 burstTokens=10
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.243899   11023 server.go:233] "Starting to serve the podresources API" endpoint="unix:/var/lib/kubelet/pod-resources/kubelet.sock"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.244384   11023 server.go:162] "Starting to listen" address="0.0.0.0" port=10250
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.244692   11023 fs_resource_analyzer.go:67] "Starting FS ResourceAnalyzer"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.246138   11023 cri_stats_provider.go:448] "Failed to get the info of the filesystem with mountpoint" err="unable to find data in memory cache" mountpoint="/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.246428   11023 event.go:289] Unable to write event: '&v1.Event{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"", APIVersion:""}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"labs-devops01.17a689716c0112f4", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink:"", UID:"", ResourceVersion:"", Generation:0, CreationTimestamp:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), DeletionTimestamp:, DeletionGracePeriodSeconds:(*int64)(nil), Labels:map[string]string(nil), Annotations:map[string]string(nil), OwnerReferences:[]v1.OwnerReference(nil), Finalizers:[]string(nil), ManagedFields:[]v1.ManagedFieldsEntry(nil)}, InvolvedObject:v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Node", Namespace:"", Name:"labs-devops01", UID:"labs-devops01", APIVersion:"", ResourceVersion:"", FieldPath:""}, Reason:"Starting", Message:"Starting kubelet.", Source:v1.EventSource{Component:"kubelet", Host:"labs-devops01"}, FirstTimestamp:time.Date(2024, time.January, 2, 14, 3, 49, 242630900, time.Local), LastTimestamp:time.Date(2024, time.January, 2, 14, 3, 49, 242630900, time.Local), Count:1, Type:"Normal", EventTime:time.Date(1, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC), Series:(*v1.EventSeries)(nil), Action:"", Related:(*v1.ObjectReference)(nil), ReportingController:"kubelet", ReportingInstance:"labs-devops01"}': 'Post "https://10.10.48.101:6443/api/v1/namespaces/default/events": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused'(may retry after sleeping)
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.247412   11023 controller.go:146] "Failed to ensure lease exists, will retry" err="Get \"https://10.10.48.101:6443/apis/coordination.k8s.io/v1/namespaces/kube-node-lease/leases/labs-devops01?timeout=10s\": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused" interval="200ms"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.247574   11023 scope.go:117] "RemoveContainer" containerID="9b512a2841561c1213167d0dc943704937419fc231fbd6a6ae3f0cdb290e24d1"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.247907   11023 volume_manager.go:291] "Starting Kubelet Volume Manager"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.248274   11023 desired_state_of_world_populator.go:151] "Desired state populator starts to run"
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: W0102 14:03:49.252512   11023 reflector.go:535] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: E0102 14:03:49.252607   11023 reflector.go:147] vendor/k8s.io/client-go/informers/factory.go:150: Failed to watch *v1.CSIDriver: failed to list *v1.CSIDriver: Get "https://10.10.48.101:6443/apis/storage.k8s.io/v1/csidrivers?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp 10.10.48.101:6443: connect: connection refused
Jan 02 14:03:49 labs-devops01 kubelet[11023]: I0102 14:03:49.253983   11023 server.go:462] "Adding debug handlers to kubelet server"
```

journalctl -u containerd:

```
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 systemd[1]: Starting containerd container runtime...
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.634500800+01:00" level=info msg="starting containerd" revision= version=1.7.2
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.659615700+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.662171200+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.aufs\"..." error="aufs is not supported (modprobe aufs failed: exit status 1 \"modprobe: FATAL: Module aufs not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-1018-azure\\n\"): skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.662206500+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.662943100+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.btrfs (ext4) must be a btrfs filesystem to be used with the btrfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.662972000+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.content.v1.content\"..." type=io.containerd.content.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663016000+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.native\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663048100+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663230600+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663295600+01:00" level=warning msg="failed to load plugin io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.devmapper" error="devmapper not configured"
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663403100+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663701000+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs\"..." error="path /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.zfs must be a zfs filesystem to be used with the zfs snapshotter: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.snapshotter.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663722000+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.metadata.v1.bolt\"..." type=io.containerd.metadata.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663754800+01:00" level=warning msg="could not use snapshotter devmapper in metadata plugin" error="devmapper not configured"
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.663784500+01:00" level=info msg="metadata content store policy set" policy=shared
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.667770200+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.differ.v1.walking\"..." type=io.containerd.differ.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.667873700+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.exchange\"..." type=io.containerd.event.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.667924200+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.gc.v1.scheduler\"..." type=io.containerd.gc.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.668099800+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.lease.v1.manager\"..." type=io.containerd.lease.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.668178700+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.nri.v1.nri\"..." type=io.containerd.nri.v1
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.668213800+01:00" level=info msg="NRI interface is disabled by configuration."
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.668282000+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.task\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.669063300+01:00" level=error msg="copy shim log after reload" error="read /proc/self/fd/7: file already closed" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.669134900+01:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=02ebd013a9e1380bd117b48f93c6ed5eb7e611e3852dba8c3bc620454a66f5c7 namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.669155200+01:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.803669200+01:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=21592c7a0ab359db3a1fdea3d87333bdee7556bf933b42c99626d974ca80df16 namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.804001100+01:00" level=error msg="copy shim log after reload" error="read /proc/self/fd/7: file already closed" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.804032900+01:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.931062600+01:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=5f8ccdeb1791fff886d060ab876548c6fc60ba485a3d31c34f073e188e569b4d namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.931104400+01:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:29 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:29.931092300+01:00" level=error msg="copy shim log after reload" error="read /proc/self/fd/7: file already closed" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.058320500+01:00" level=error msg="copy shim log after reload" error="read /proc/self/fd/7: file already closed" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.058322500+01:00" level=warning msg="cleaning up after shim disconnected" id=da93704ac23c63fa269bc1db379e1099d346331165ffe0cc3dea7aef35fc178c namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.058410900+01:00" level=info msg="cleaning up dead shim" namespace=k8s.io
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.202993600+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.runtime.v2.shim\"..." type=io.containerd.runtime.v2
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.203040100+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.sandbox.store.v1.local\"..." type=io.containerd.sandbox.store.v1
--------Around 30 other plugins loading... ---------
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204438300+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri\"..." type=io.containerd.grpc.v1
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204749600+01:00" level=info msg="Start cri plugin with config {PluginConfig:{ContainerdConfig:{Snapshotter:overlayfs DefaultRuntimeName:runc DefaultRuntime:{Type: Path: Engine: PodAnnotations:[] ContainerAnnotations:[] Root: Options:map[] PrivilegedWithoutHostDevices:false PrivilegedWithoutHostDevicesAllDevicesAllowed:false BaseRuntimeSpec: NetworkPluginConfDir: NetworkPluginMaxConfNum:0 Snapshotter: SandboxMode:} UntrustedWorkloadRuntime:{Type: Path: Engine: PodAnnotations:[] ContainerAnnotations:[] Root: Options:map[] PrivilegedWithoutHostDevices:false PrivilegedWithoutHostDevicesAllDevicesAllowed:false BaseRuntimeSpec: NetworkPluginConfDir: NetworkPluginMaxConfNum:0 Snapshotter: SandboxMode:} Runtimes:map[runc:{Type:io.containerd.runc.v2 Path: Engine: PodAnnotations:[] ContainerAnnotations:[] Root: Options:map[BinaryName: CriuImagePath: CriuPath: CriuWorkPath: IoGid:0 IoUid:0 NoNewKeyring:false NoPivotRoot:false Root: ShimCgroup: SystemdCgroup:true] PrivilegedWithoutHostDevices:false PrivilegedWithoutHostDevicesAllDevicesAllowed:false BaseRuntimeSpec: NetworkPluginConfDir: NetworkPluginMaxConfNum:0 Snapshotter: SandboxMode:podsandbox}] NoPivot:false DisableSnapshotAnnotations:true DiscardUnpackedLayers:false IgnoreBlockIONotEnabledErrors:false IgnoreRdtNotEnabledErrors:false} CniConfig:{NetworkPluginBinDir:/opt/cni/bin NetworkPluginConfDir:/etc/cni/net.d NetworkPluginMaxConfNum:1 NetworkPluginSetupSerially:false NetworkPluginConfTemplate: IPPreference:} Registry:{ConfigPath: Mirrors:map[] Configs:map[] Auths:map[] Headers:map[]} ImageDecryption:{KeyModel:node} DisableTCPService:true StreamServerAddress:127.0.0.1 StreamServerPort:0 StreamIdleTimeout:4h0m0s EnableSelinux:false SelinuxCategoryRange:1024 SandboxImage:k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.5 StatsCollectPeriod:10 SystemdCgroup:false EnableTLSStreaming:false X509KeyPairStreaming:{TLSCertFile: TLSKeyFile:} MaxContainerLogLineSize:16384 DisableCgroup:false DisableApparmor:false RestrictOOMScoreAdj:false MaxConcurrentDownloads:3 DisableProcMount:false UnsetSeccompProfile: TolerateMissingHugetlbController:true DisableHugetlbController:true DeviceOwnershipFromSecurityContext:false IgnoreImageDefinedVolumes:false NetNSMountsUnderStateDir:false EnableUnprivilegedPorts:false EnableUnprivilegedICMP:false EnableCDI:false CDISpecDirs:[/etc/cdi /var/run/cdi] ImagePullProgressTimeout:1m0s DrainExecSyncIOTimeout:0s} ContainerdRootDir:/var/lib/containerd ContainerdEndpoint:/run/containerd/containerd.sock RootDir:/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri StateDir:/run/containerd/io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri}"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204820700+01:00" level=info msg="Connect containerd service"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204849400+01:00" level=info msg="using legacy CRI server"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204859800+01:00" level=info msg="using experimental NRI integration - disable nri plugin to prevent this"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.204895900+01:00" level=info msg="Get image filesystem path \"/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs\""
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205486600+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205514900+01:00" level=info msg="skip loading plugin \"io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1.otlp\"..." error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin" type=io.containerd.tracing.processor.v1
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205530900+01:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.tracing\"..." type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205544700+01:00" level=info msg="skipping tracing processor initialization (no tracing plugin)" error="no OpenTelemetry endpoint: skip plugin"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205904300+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/run/containerd/containerd.sock.ttrpc
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.205904400+01:00" level=info msg="Start subscribing containerd event"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.206589400+01:00" level=info msg=serving... address=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.207505800+01:00" level=info msg="Start recovering state"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.408885000+01:00" level=info msg="Start event monitor"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.408931000+01:00" level=info msg="Start snapshots syncer"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.408951600+01:00" level=info msg="Start cni network conf syncer for default"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.408972500+01:00" level=info msg="Start streaming server"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 containerd[10942]: time="2024-01-02T14:03:30.409149500+01:00" level=info msg="containerd successfully booted in 0.776054s"
Jan 02 14:03:30 labs-devops01 systemd[1]: Started containerd container runtime.
```

Relevant running processes (ps -aux):

```
root       11023  1.5  1.3 1635776 108328 ?      Ssl  14:03   0:08 /usr/bin/kubelet --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --config=/var/lib/kubelet/
root       11089  0.0  0.2 722280 21048 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 17c8c395e6b079f220da7204cbd3c6b12e676c74cc7fc7816e34787e6c3e6525 -address /run/containerd/co
root       11097  0.0  0.2 722536 19692 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 167c473122d62b31acfd5e84e9bf23afc588653a352263c4fdd6fb3b4674b9bd -address /run/containerd/co
root       11148  0.0  0.2 722280 20920 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id d2f0dd19c0d5cbaa1b36acb368552b134558ce4b20a5179b61750eae061c55d7 -address /run/containerd/co
root       11150  0.0  0.2 722280 19604 ?        Sl   14:03   0:00 /usr/bin/containerd-shim-runc-v2 -namespace k8s.io -id 7dcac32c789d7d264f8f71b9467853ac60741a5b6399e071bb358bcedf37936d -address /run/containerd/co
root       11328  0.4  1.0 831292 85068 ?        Ssl  14:03   0:02 kube-controller-manager --allocate-node-cidrs=true --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/
root       11338  0.9  0.7 11214912 56368 ?      Ssl  14:03   0:05 etcd --advertise-client-urls=https://10.10.48.101:2379 --cert-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/server.crt --client-cert-auth=true --data-dir=/var/lib/
root       11345  0.6  0.7 765000 57108 ?        Ssl  14:03   0:03 kube-scheduler --authentication-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --authorization-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf --bind-address=
root       12242  0.1  0.4 744520 33716 ?        Sl   14:12   0:00 /opt/cni/bin/calico
```